# Traefik v2 BasicAuth Middleware: having troubles enabling auth for any container different than Dashboard

Tags: docker, traefik, traefik-authentication

I'm not really an expert and I'm working on Traefik with Docker for the first time: ideally, I would like to expose a service *(ie. a Docker Container with a ready-to-use-app, in this example Koodo Reader)* while being protected from *massively easy public access****^(*)* using a BasicAuth Middleware, much like it's done with the Traefik Dashboard Example.

This is the `docker-compose.yml` I'm using for Traefik:

```
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.5"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--entrypoints.webbooks.address=:8018"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.dnschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.dnschallenge.provider=dynu"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=xxxxxx"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
      # Global HTTP -> HTTPS
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
      # Enable dashboard
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      # Patch Unifi
      - "--serversTransport.insecureSkipVerify=true"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "853:853"
      - "53:53"
      - "53:53/udp"

    environment:
      - "DYNU_API_KEY=xxxxxx"
      - "DYNU_HTTP_TIMEOUTY=300"
      - "DYNU_POLLING_INTERVAL=200"
      - "DYNU_PROPAGATION_TIMEOUT=250"
      - "DYNU_TTL=120"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  whoami:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    container_name: "traefik-whoami"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`xxxxxx.dynu.net`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.middlewares=auth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=user:xxxhashpassxxx
```

This configuration works, and I receive an auth prompt when accessing the Traefik Dashboard.

The other container is an instance of Koodo, controlled through Portainer Business. These are the `labels` attached to the `Koodo` container, which I'm able to access via *https* at my own *xxxxxx**.dynu.net* address; but still, no authorization is required.

I'm quite sure this has to do with a macroscopic error on my side, but I couldn't figure it out. And all *tutorials/guides/docs* I could read always points to the same "easy" solution: defining a `basicauth.users` `middelware` and then assigning/calling it.

```
traefik.http.middlewares.Koodo-redirect-websecure.redirectscheme.scheme = https
traefik.http.routers.Koodo-web.entrypoints = web
traefik.http.routers.Koodo-web.middlewares = Koodo-redirect-websecure
traefik.http.routers.Koodo-web.rule = Host(`xxxxxx.dynu.net`)
traefik.http.routers.Koodo-websecure.entrypoints = websecure
traefik.http.routers.Koodo-websecure.rule = Host(`xxxxxx.dynu.net`)
traefik.http.routers.Koodo-websecure.tls = true
traefik.http.routers.Koodo-websecure.tls.certresolver = myresolver
traefik.http.middlewares.kauth.basicauth.users = neoread:xxxxxxx
traefik.http.routers.Koodo.middlewares= kauth
traefik.http.services.Koodo-websecure.loadbalancer.server.port = 80
```

Thank you in advance for your time reading this and any insight you may want to share.

Comment: Hi @NeoMod, did you check the traefik access logs for any clue?

Comment: Any progress here?